# Thread communication In simple java program and in Java web application

Tags: java, servlets

How thread communication work is different in web application and Simple java Program.  Please guide me on below query. Try to narrate question please ignore grammatical mistake.

Suppose i have simple java class

```
package com.scjp.chapter.Exception;
public class ThreadException extends Thread{
        public void run(){
        show();
        display();
    }

    private void display() {
        System.out.println(ThreadException.currentThread().getName() + " Display");
    }

    private void show() {
        int i = 10/0;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadException thread1 = new ThreadException();
        ThreadException thread2 = new ThreadException();
        ThreadException thread3= new ThreadException();

        thread1.setName("thread1");
        thread2.setName("thread2");
        thread3.setName("thread3");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();

    }
}
```

Above program will not print display content.All three is throwing show method Arithmetic exception.
But if we call display() before to show(). Then program is generating output of display() as well as throwing Arithmetic exception also.And output order is changing.
So my question is why display() method output is not coming when will calling show() before display() ?.

According to Exception concept below line should not execute after the exception throw so if thread1 is throwing exception then other thread two thread should not execute further code.

Comment: Threads run independently. Why would one thread throwing an exception cause other threads to stop?

Answer (score 0):

> why display() method output is not coming when will calling show() before display() ?

Because show() throws an exception, which thus causes the method execution to stop.

> if thread1 is throwing exception then other thread two thread should not execute further code

Yes, it should, because a each thread has its own... thread of execution. Its instructions are executed in parallel to the other threads of execution, and the exception thrown in a thread doesn't have any impact on a separate thread. That's basically the whole point of threads.

> How thread communication work is different in web application and Simple java Program

It's not.